# Fortran I/O 4 byte record

Tags: io, fortran, binaryfiles

When writing data with Fortran, I understand a 4 byte "record" is written before and after the data.  Usually I already know what I am reading so I just discard it.  However, is any information contained in these records?  Is it possible to obtain the datatype and count of the data following the record, from the 4 byte record information?

Comment: If you are on Linux you can od -x the file to see what is in it.  On windows powershell, you can format-hex the file.

Answer (score 5):

By "binary" you most likely mean `access="sequential", form="unformatted"` but there are other types of access Fortran can do, namely `direct` and `stream`.

Firstly, the data that *you* save in each `write` statement is the **"record"**. What the Fortran compiler writes itself is the **"record marker"**. It says where the next record of data is.

Typically, Fortran will write the length of the record to the record marker. Why? Because the access is sequential, from record to record. When you read the next record, the compiler needs to know where it begins. Or when you go back using `backspace`.

Please note that the record markers are not always 4-byte long. That is only sufficient for records under 4GB. You can certainly meet also 8-byte record markers. The actual Format is compiler-dependent and not standardized.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding, and others might contradict me here, is that the format of the binary write is not standardized. When last I looked at it (intel fortran and gfortran) it seemed to be an unsigned integer of the length of the record in bytes, and it's repeated at the end of the record, but I'm not sure.

I would look into storing data as a stream (newer versions of Fortran only) for more control over what's written.

Comment: There are some platforms where the length is recorded by the file system and isn't part of the data. While four-byte lengths are most common now, there is a convention for records longer than 1GB, shared by ifort and gfortran, that break these up into segments with the length encoding a flag as to whether it's the first, last or only physical record.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that chw21 is correct.  what "extras" get written depends on the compiler and (more importantly) the characteristics of the file in the open statement.

i use the Lahey/Fujitsu compiler, and when I need exact control over what is in the file with no extras, i open the file of type "binary".  This generates no extra, no record formatting, nothing.  It allows you to read and write binary data to a file with confidence.

Comment: Note binary is not standard - as chw12 says stream is the standard way to do it.

Comment: And if not stream than the good old direct also normally avoids record markers. Records of equal size are required.